# excel VBA code to Copy and Paste a set of data with a finite amount (count)

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

In excel on a single sheet, I have a blank template and a set of raw data on the side which needs to be inserted into the template. I need help creating the VBA code to copy and paste the data into the template with it not pasting any extra cells (stop at the end of the data). My raw data changes and should be able to be any length of rows but it is always constant from columns Z:AL. I am interesting in moving it to columns A5:M5.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest code I can think of. You might want to throw a worksheet reference in front of the Range and I included a couple of methods of finding the end of the range. I prefer the 3rd method.

```
  dest = "A5"
  wsName = "DataSheet"

  With Worksheets(wsName)
    endRow1 = .Range("Z1").End(xlDown).Row
    endRow2 = .Range("Z105000").End(xlUp).Row
    endRow3 = .Range("Z:AL").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    .Range("Z1:AL" & endRow3).Copy Destination:=Range(dest)

  End With
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are not blanks in a column in the dataset (I assume column Z) then you can use Range.End to get the last row.  I try to avoid using Copy/Paste in macros, because there's a faster way to do it.

```
Option Explicit
Sub MoveDataRange()
    Dim dest As Range, endRow As Integer

    With Worksheets("DataSheet")
        endRow = .Range("Z1").End(xlDown).Row
        Set dest = .Range("A5").Resize(endRow, 13)   '13 columns between Z:AL
        dest.Value = .Range("Z1:AL" & endRow).Value
    End With
End Sub
```